# Finding duplicate Contacts in Recent Contacts View

Tags: lotusscript

I need to write code for finding duplicate entries in recent contact view within same internal domain. I'm not going to touch external internet contacts. Is there any special Property or method to do it (in lotus script?)  comparing all the view entries with server nab is the good idea? can anyone suggest me best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully get what you need, but here is what I suggest

I would suggest to write small bunch of code that walk via view (Recent Contacts) and create a list and put there only unique pair of key/doc and store in another place all duplicates.

you can create an agent with such code (please notice, I may use wrong key, so just define what field for you is a unique key) i.e.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim view As NotesView
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim uniquedocs List As Variant
Dim duplicates As string
Dim key As String

Set view = session.Currentdatabase.Getview("(Recent Contacts)")
Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
While Not doc Is Nothing
    ' this is the unique key, please change it if you need
    key = doc.Getitemvalue("MailDomain")(0)

    If key <> "" Then
        If Not IsElement(uniquedocs(key)) Then
            Set uniquedocs(key) = doc
        Else
            If duplicates <> "" Then duplicates = duplicates & " | "
            duplicates = duplicates & key
        End If
    End If

    Set doc = view.Getnextdocument(doc)
Wend

MsgBox duplicates
```

duplicates - is a string with all mail domains that have at least 2 contacts in view (Recent Contacts)

Comment: Let me clearly tell my Requirement,

I need to get all the entries from local names.nsf then i need to compare each document(contacts) with servers NAB, if is not exists i need to delete that contact or document from local names.nsf

Comment: i tried the code as below,

First i will get the fullname values from "people " View of server NAB and store them in string array.

Is this best way to do this? 

then i will get all the entries from local NAB , 

then inside loop i will compare fullname each contacts  (in recent contact view) with the servers array of fullname 

if it return false which is duplicate so i ll remove from local nab.

Comment: yes, what you wrote is right way, I would do same as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Initialize
On Error GoTo errHandler

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim currdb As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim view1 As NotesView
Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim namesentry As NotesViewEntry
Dim serdoc As NotesDocument
Dim localdoc As NotesDocument
Dim item As NotesItem


Dim dname As String
Dim serverfullName() As String
Dim localfulName As String
Dim formula As String
Dim result As Variant
Dim count As Integer 

'Getting all the documents from servers NAB ,put that in document collection
Set db=session.GetDatabase("Myserver","names.nsf")
Set view=db.GetView("People")
Set vc = view.AllEntries
Set namesentry = vc.Getfirstentry()
ReDim Serverfullname(CInt(vc.Count))
count = 0

'storing fullnames in array
While Not namesentry Is Nothing

    Set serdoc = namesentry.Document
    serverfullName(count) = serdoc.Getitemvalue("FullName")(0)
    Set namesentry = vc.Getnextentry(namesentry)
    count = count + 1
Wend 
'keeping the string format for Comparison   
Dim x As String
Dim iteration As Integer
x = ""
iteration = 0
ForAll i In Serverfullname
    iteration = iteration + 1
    If i ="" Then
    ElseIf count = iteration Then   
        x = x + |"| + i + |"|
    Else
        x = x + |"| + i + |"| + ":"
    End If
End ForAll
'MsgBox x 'Displaying servers fullname list

'Geetting local NAB contacts
Set currdb= session.CurrentDatabase
Dim selFormula As String
'creating New view to filter documents with same domain
selFormula= {SELECT @UpperCase($AutoCreatedList)  = "DIP" & @LowerCase(MailDomain)=@LowerCase("mydomain")}
Call currdb.Createview("RecentView",selFormula)
Set view1 = currdb.GetView("RecentView")
Set localdoc = view1.GetFirstDocument


While Not localdoc Is Nothing 

    localfulName = localdoc.Getitemvalue("FullName")(0)
    Dim indexresult As Variant
    Dim Formula1 As String

    Formula1 = |@Contains(| & x & |;"| + Localfulname + |")|
    'MsgBox Formula1
    indexresult = Evaluate(Formula1)
    If indexresult(0)= 0 Then

        MsgBox " Duplicate entry " & localfulname & "."
        'Call localdoc.Remove(true)
    End If

    Set localdoc = view1.Getnextdocument(localdoc)
Wend
Exit sub
```

errHandler:
    MsgBox Error() & " "  & Erl()
    Exit sub
End Sub